# jQuery Clone Not Selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having some issues selecting elements that jquery clones. Below is what I have. I can't seem to select the .remove-container class anchor from the cloned versions. The only one that I can select is the original.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="primary">
      <div class="quote-container">
        <label>Quote </label>
        <textarea rows=5></textarea>
        <label>Author</label>
        <input type="text" name="author" />
        <a href="#remove" class="remove-container">Remove</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#add" class="add-container">Add</a>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".add-container").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".quote-container").eq(0).clone().insertBefore(".add-container");
        var qContainer = $(".quote-container").length;

        for (i=0; i<qContainer; i++) {
          if ($(".quote-container").eq(i).find("label").html() === "Quote "+(i+1)) {
          } else {
            $(".quote-container").eq(i).find("label").eq(0).replaceWith("<label>Quote "+(i+1)+"</label>");
          }
        }
      });
      $(".remove-container").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this));
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed your remove link jQuery to this everything worked (as I think you're wanting it to):

```
$('#primary').on('click', 'a.remove-container', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/gw3mq/

One thing to know is if you remove all quote rows, clicking the add link won't do anything, since it won't have anything to clone anymore.

Comment: but live isn't chainable nor is it a best practice anymore. the only solution that I've found to really work at the moment is by adding `true` into the clone paramenter.

Comment: Hmm did you just changed your response?

Comment: No, but someone else had posted an answer using `.live`, which I also commented about `.live` being deprecated on.  It has since been deleted.

Comment: ahh, its working on jsfiddling, but isn't on my browser... however when I replaced `clone()` to `clone(true)` it works... would you know the reason?

Comment: Haha, I guess they deleted the comment.

Comment: Per the jQuery docs: withDataAndEventsA Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value is false. *In jQuery 1.5.0 the default value was incorrectly true; it was changed back to false in 1.5.1 and up.  http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: I don't quite understand that, what's that mean in layman's term?

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in the console with your fix.

Comment: Sounds like you missed a closing ' or } or ) somewhere.